# Move folder & sub folders to a new folder keeping folder structure

Tags: vb.net

I want to move this folder and any sub folders & files below it .

```
\\server\Paperport\Sales\Jobs\26500-26549\
```

to

```
\\server\Archives\Jobs\
```

it needs to look like

```
\\server\Archives\Jobs\26500-26549\ 
\\server\Archives\Jobs\26500-26549\XYZ
```

The subs folders will have sub folders.
is it easier to just call a batch file using the xcopy command ?

EDIT:

So I have tried everything i could find but didnt add it as I felt it was unnecessary to mention due to it not being directly related for future viewers of this thread;

So my research found;

```
my.computer.movedirectory(folder, destlocation) - only moves the files in the folder
movefile(folder, destlocation) - only used for moving a file
```

MSDN showed there is no direct function, hence the post.

so now I have given you the fluff, can we please move on a solution ?

Comment: Great. What have you tried?

Comment: looking  on google, checking msdn there is not a function for moving folders like there is this files, there is only a function to move the files to a new directory"My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveDirectory"  , and looking on here, all off which have returned nothing that has worked, hence the post.

Comment: Hence @Jungle_Jon I don't think you haven't read [ask] or [mcve] as you would have seen we ask people to try code and something before asking for help? Specially as this can easily be solved by recursivity

Comment: AFAIK `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveDirectory` should work. You say it only moves the files in the folder, and not the subdirectories?

Comment: so im using  'My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(path(2), newfolder(count))' and the files get moved but not the folder as well, that gets deleted.